# How to make htmx colour animations work with Django?

Tags: css, django, htmx

I have a simple Django project. I'm trying to get this example HTMX colour changing element working.
https://htmx.org/examples/animations/

I have copied and pasted the exact code they use into my Django index.html file:

```
<style>
.smooth {
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
</style>
<div id="color-demo" class="smooth" style="color:red"
      hx-get="/colors" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="every 1s">
  Color Swap Demo
</div>
<script>
    var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red'];
    onGet("/colors", function () {
      var color = colors.shift();
      colors.push(color);
      return '<div id="color-demo" hx-get="/colors" hx-swap="outerHTML" class="smooth" hx-trigger="every 1s" style="color:' + color + '">\n'+
             '  Color Swap Demo\n'+
             '</div>\n'
    });
</script>
```

This prints out the following:
[image]
But unlike what is shown in the demo, it doesn't change  colours every 1 second.

My command line for the Django server keeps throwing this error every 1 second:
[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a `/colors` endpoint in your project? If not, you either must create one or remove that from the code.

Comment: I do not. How would I go about creating one for the above example?

Comment: Write a view function that returns a `div` with a color. HTMX swaps the new div with the old one. If the new one has different color, then the animations fires and you see the 1s transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error, because the url is invalid. You need to use the correct path in the hx-get to an exisiting view (something like `hx-get="{% url 'colorapp:color_swap' %}"`). Also, your view function needs to return a `div` with a color, where the color changes every second. You could use a loop, or simply change the color based on the current time in seconds.

You could do something like this:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import views

app_name = "colorapp"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("color_swap/", views.color_swap, name="color_swap"),
    ]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import time

def color_swap(request):
    now = round(time.time()/2,0)
    print(now)
    if (now % 2) == 0:
        color_name = "red"
    else:
        color_name = "blue"
    return render(
        request=request,
        template_name="colorapp/color_swap.html",
        context={"color_name": color_name}
    )
```

**swap_colors.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<style>
  .smooth {
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
  }
</style>
<div id="color-demo" 
     class="smooth" 
     style="color:{{color_name}}"
     hx-get="{% url 'colorapp:color_swap' %}" 
     hx-swap="outerHTML" 
     hx-trigger="every 1s">
    Color Swap Demo
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.8.6"></script>
    <script>
      document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) => {
        event.detail.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = '{{ csrf_token }}';
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Depending on your use case, it could be easier to implement this without the server requests using a local javascript.

Comment: I saw this a bit late, but thank you very much for this